# RTSP Feed Screen Cutoff

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc, rtsp, ip-camera

Recently I have been trying to consume the RTSP stream from a *Vivitar Folding Drone*. By reverse-engineering the *.apk* file for the *Vivitar Folding Drone* app, I was able to find that the RTSP address for the drone is `rtsp://192.168.1.1:7070/webcam` however, whenever I consume this stream through VLC or FFPLAY, most of the feed gets cut off and replaced with a green screen or gray screen (depends on whether I save to a *.mjpeg* file or a *.dump* file). What is the cause of this problem and what steps can I take to fix it?

[image]

When using FFPLAY, I use the following command:

```
ffplay -i -rtsp_flags rtsp://192.168.1.1:7070/webcam
```

I also receive this error when I first start consuming the stream with `ffplay` :

```
[swscaler @ 00000240daeadf80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
```

I receive this error message for about every frame of the stream:

```
[mjpeg @ 00000240d6226b00] mjpeg_decode_dc: bad vlc: 0:0 (00000240d6266050)
[mjpeg @ 00000240d6226b00] error dc
[mjpeg @ 00000240d6226b00] error y=1 x=0
```

**NOTE:** I am unsure if this is relevant, but the Vivitar Drone creates its own wifi network that must be signed onto if you want to consume the RTSP stream

Also, the drone feed works perfectly fine when viewed through the *Vivitar Folding Drone* app. I just can't seem to get it to display properly through FFPLAY, FFMPEG, or VLC.

**UPDATE**:

Upon further inspection, it seems like the *Vivitar Folding Drone* may not be sending all of the **jpg** data for a single frame. Here is an image generated by unaltered byte data sent through the RTSP feed.
[image]

I noticed three things from this image:

1. The image appears to be missing large chunks of data.
2. The image appears to be redshifted
3. The two visible portions of the image should be sequential (it looks as though the second visual portion lines up with the first). An example of this can be seen below.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the JPEG restart marker standard being broken by the Vivitar Software. A more detailed explanation and solution by **cehoyo** can be found [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8211). I forked a version of the FFMPEG project and have applied the changes from **cehoyo**'s solution on the FFMPEG forum in this Git [fork](https://github.com/MrMiracleMan111/FFmpeg).